# I don't know if a question about computer appliances belongs in Super User stack

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, superuser

I have a question about possibilities of appliances using thunderbolt enabled USB-C ports and if they have the capability of powering a device and video on the same port. I won't into the specifics but I don't know if this kind of question belongs on Super User -- described as "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users" -- or if there's a stack that pertains to more technical hardware question such as this.

Comment: Maybe ask on [its meta](https://meta.superuser.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examining SuperUser's on-topic questions as well as their 'don't asks', as long as you ask an objective question about whether Thunderbolt enabled USB-C can perform the task you desire, it should be on topic.

However, if you are looking for hardware that would support your desired functionality the in-beta [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is where you would want to go; They are targeted at helping to find hardware that meets your requirements.